# Dagger2: Field injection in ViewModel which has compile time and run time dependencies

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I have a list of Students which is displayed in `RecyclerView` and for each Student, I have `StudentViewModel`. As the `StudentViewModel` needs `Student` object which is retrieved runtime from database, I am not sure how can I setup constructor injection for `StudentViewModel` so I didn't attempt DI here. However, now I need another dependency in the viewmodel which can be resolved compile time and which is my `NavUtil` class.

I managed to get it injected in my `StudentViewModel` with following lines:

```
DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(MyApp.INSTANCE)
                .build()
                .inject(this)
```

But I don't think this is the correct way as I am referring Application class from my ViewModel just for the sake of DI. I read it might be possible with `ViewModelFactory`, but I am not able to find any solid example or reference to this. I am already using it for the ViewModels which has compile-time dependencies though, but not able to figure out the way for **`ViewModel`(s) which has compile time and rumtime dependencies**. Would be great if someone could point me in right direction.

BTW here's my overall implementation for DI:

**App Component**

```
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class, AppProvider::class,StudentProvider::class])

@Singleton
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: MyApp)
    fun inject(studentViewModel: StudentViewModel)
```

**StudentProvider**

```
@Module
abstract class StudentProvider {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [(ViewModelModule::class)])
    abstract fun bindHomeActivity(): HomeActivity
}
```

**ViewModelModules**

```
@Module
class ViewModelModule {

    @ActivityContext
    @Provides
    fun provideNavUtils(activity: Activity): NavUtil = NavUtil(activity)
}
```

**StudentViewModel**

```
class StudentViewModel(student: Student) : BaseViewModel() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var navUtils: NavUtil

    init {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(MyApp.INSTANCE)
                .build()
                .inject(this)
    }

    fun onSettingsTapped() {
        navUtils.navigateToSettings()
    }
}
```

**NavUtil**

```
class NavUtil @Inject constructor(@ActivityContext private val context: Context) {

    fun navigateToSettings() {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, SettingsActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: It looks like activity context is not getting inject and instead, Application context is inject.

Comment: I think you have 2 problems, one is that you're using `@ActivityContext` wrongly, that's a scope not a qualifier. The other is that `StudentProvider` should be a class that belongs to the data layer, you should provide it via a dagger Module but it shouldn't be a module itself.

Comment: My data layer is `StudentRepository`. `StudentProvider` is my module which binds Student module related views like `StudentsActivity, SettingsActivity` with DI. Not sure if naming convention is wrong, but it's specifically the DI module for me :) Reharding `@ActivityContext`, yes it's scope and if I make it `Qualifier` it won't compile saying `Qualifiers can't be used with @ ContributesAndroidInjector` or something.